# Rails SQLite no such table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, nginx

I am still struggling a bit with Rails and nginx, however I got most of it sorted out. Now, if I enable the server with `rails -s`, all works fine and I can see all articles, if I connect to the IP with the port of 3000. With nginx I am getting the following error however:

```
App 30780 stderr: Started GET "/articles" for 188.193.201.119 at 2014-02-10 17:57:51 +0000
App 30780 stderr: Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
App 30780 stderr: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: articles: SELECT "articles".* FROM "articl$
App 30780 stderr:   Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.1ms)
App 30780 stderr: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
App 30780 stderr:
App 30780 stderr: ActionView::Template::Error (SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: articles: SEL$
App 30780 stderr:     12:   </thead>
```

With the rails console all of the articles can be found as well as, if I run the rails server manually. Why is it giving me here an error however? :-/

Comment: This has nothing to do with nginx. It looks like your query is referencing a column you don't have defined.

Answer (score 4):

Resolved the issue with `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`